# Add panels to my form on every button click, which look simple to the default panel in c#

Tags: c#

[my timer application is simple. I am facing problem when i am trying to add multiple tasks using existing panel i have uploaded a image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTaUR.jpg) here is the code which i have tryed(panel1 is allready added to form using panel1 we need to create new panels which are nothing but there copy of panel1 which has same funcationlty as panel1)

```
private void btn_addtimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    itf = new Input_task_form();
    DialogResult dr = itf.ShowDialog();

    if (dr == DialogResult.OK) {
        //lbl_text.Text =itf.Task_name;
        //Height = Height + 234;
        //this.Size = new Size(535, Height);
        //this.panel1.Show();
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        panel1 = new Panel();
        this.lbl_text.Text = itf.Task_name;
        Height = Height + 234;
        this.Size = new Size(535, Height);
        panel1.Show();
        this.panel1.Name = "panel" + pcount.ToString();

    }
    else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel) {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked on Cancel");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: can u see any image!!!

Comment: I can see the image, but it's simply a list of requirements. We don't do projects for people here. What *particular* issue are you facing?

Comment: I believe your teacher can guide you on this, and you need to understand how to add control first ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h5y8567(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: can any one add code inside if statement for creating panel on every button

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do anything:

```
panel1.Show();
```

Instead of `panel1.Show()`, you want to add the panel to the form:

```
this.Controls.Add(panel1);
```

Additionally, you want to set the `Top` and `Left` properties for the panel to something sensible. It looks like you may be confusing the `Height` property for `Top`. One option to consider is a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) or similar as parent control for these items.